# Is there a way to use multiple targets in a SQL `ON CONFLICT` clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to modify a seed script to not insert duplicate records in a postgres db when run multiple times. In one of the tables, each record has a `deleted_at` column, which can be either `NULL` (default) or a timestamp (`2021-11-12 19:24:47.164380 +00:00`). There can be only one record that has a `NULL` value, and one record with any given timestamp; only one record may be active, and multiple records may have been deleted at some point in the past.

I have two unique indexes on this table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX deleted_idx
    ON values (m_id, pp_id, deleted_at)
        WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX active_idx
    ON values (m_id, pp_id, (deleted_at IS NULL))
        WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

The problem is, in order to use these indexes to prevent duplicates without causing the seed script to error out, I need to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO values(m_id, pp_id, deleted_at, ...)
VALUES ('96313007-01e9-42e8-b946-58cc05ce2c8d', '3d8f3be5-a419-4252-acba-7a3eb40ae095', NULL, ...)
ON CONFLICT (m_id, pp_id, (deleted_at IS NULL))
    DO NOTHING; 
ON CONFLICT (m_id, pp_id, deleted_at)
    DO NOTHING;
```

Keep in mind, `m_id` is not the PKEY. Obviously I can't do this though, since having two `ON CONFLICT` clauses isn't valid syntax.

Is there a way I can have two `ON CONFLICT` targets? Due to business needs, modifying the seed script to insert specific PKEYs so I could just simply enforce uniqueness on the PKEY would be a big deal.

Comment: If those are the only two unique indexes, you can simply use `on conflict do nothing`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name surprised it's that simple!